# Titanium notification (android toast) with image

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to show an image as a toast instead of plain text message.
I have tried:

```
try{
  var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
    duration: Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG,
    background: '/images/img1.png'
  });
  toast.show();
}
catch (err)
{
  alert(err.message);
}
```

Application gets crashed without giving any alert. I have also tried :

```
try{
  var toast = Titanium.UI.createNotification({
    duration: Ti.UI.NOTIFICATION_DURATION_LONG,
    message: 'text',
  });
  toast.setBackgroundImage('/images/img1.png');
  toast.show();
}
catch (err)
{
  alert(err.message);
}
```

But same issue. App crashes without giving error alert. Anyone knows how to give image in toast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by the functions below. I have decide fade-out time as per my requirement (i.e. 10% of total time). This code may need to handle back button pressed event manually.

```
var createImageToast = function (img, time)
{
    Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
    var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
      image: img,
    });
    win.add(image);
    win.open();
    setTimeout(function(){
        decreaseImageOpacity(win,image,1,parseInt(time/10));
    },parseInt(time*9/10));
}
var decreaseImageOpacity = function (win, image, opacity, time)
{
    if(opacity<=0)
    {
        win.close();
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            image.setOpacity(''+opacity);
            decreaseImageOpacity(win,image,opacity-0.1, time);
        },parseInt(time/10));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed '..' in the background image path.

**/images/img1.png** should be: **../images/img1.png**

Comment: no answer you suggested does not work either. can you show your code where it works?